# how to sendkeys to textbox with selenium on vba excel

Tags: vba, selenium

[image]

```
selenium.FindElementByXPath("/html/body/div[1]/div[1]/div[3]/div[2]/div[1]/div[3]/ul/ul/li[13]/ul/li[18]/a").SendKeys ("TEST")
```

don't work

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read why [a screenshot of code is a bad idea](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303812/discourage-screenshots-of-code-and-or-errors). Paste the code and properly format it instead.

Answer (score 0):

As per the `HTML` you have shared we can use the following line of code to send any text as follows :

```
selenium.FindElementByXPath("//td[@title='Site Code']//following::input[starts-with(@name,'prop_')][@value='ATG0002T']").SendKeys ("TEST")
```

Comment: Did you try the `xpath` I have provided in my answer?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this xpath

```
//input[contains(@name,'prop_') and contains(@value='ATG0002T')]").SendKeys ("TEST")
```